# Can jQuery DateTime parse this date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a datetime of the form:

```
var myDate = "2013-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"
```

I wish to do

```
jQuery.datepicker.parseDate( "yy-mm-dd", myDate);
```

I don't care about the time part.

I get:

```
"Extra/unparsed characters found in date: T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Best I got so far is:

```
myDate = myDate.replace('T00:00:00.000Z', '');
myDate = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", myDate).toUTCString();
```

Please help.

Comment: You have to change the parser string

Comment: try date.js , a free library

Answer (score 20):

As it is ISO date format, I think you can call `new Date(myDate)` directly there is no need to parse it *I think*

```
var date = new Date(myDate);
```

Comment: This seems to be valid for Chrome and IE, but Firefox is not going to parse it.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about the time part, why not simply

```
jQuery.datepicker.parseDate( "yy-mm-dd", myDate.split("T")[0]);
```

Perhaps for general DateTime handling, have a look at 
[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: TO said, that the format is fix, why shouldn't it work? Does split sometimes take a vacation?

Comment: You have forgotten to close your parenthesis. +1-ing because this answer does what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```
var myDate = "2013-06-07T00:00:00.000Z";
var n=myDate.split("T");
console.log(n); // Pass the date part only to date picker
```

Answer (score 0):

By modifying the *String* used to describe the format, you can get it to do this (assuming time is always zero)

```
var myDate = "2013-06-07T00:00:00.000Z",
    d = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z", myDate);
d; // Fri Jun 07 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

However, this will ignore the fact that `Z` denotes timezone `UTC` and instead uses local timezone (in my case BST/`GMT+1`). You can repair this quickly though.

```
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset()); // or use UTCMinutes
d; // Thu Jun 07 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
// which is now correct in terms of timezone
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that will change your life, just use http://momentjs.com/... It's the equivalent of Carbon for PHP. Simple, multi-language and cross-browsers.

For your question, it goes :

```
moment("2013-06-07T00:00:00.000Z").format('YY-MM-DD')
```

Hope this helps future visitors.

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

```
jQuery.datepicker.parseDate( "yy-mm-dd", myDate.substr(0, 10) );
```

Comment: What you mean? Can you argue, because now you don't help anyone.